# how to get specific part of a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, text, python-re, pypdf

I have PDF file. I wanna get some different part of text.

for example let I have the following page:

```
0021 Literacy and numeracy
Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed 
to teach fundamental skills in reading, writing and arithmetic. The typical age range of 
participants can be used to distinguish between detailed field 0011 ‘Basic programmes and 
qualifications’ and this detailed field. 
Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here:
Basic remedial programmes for youth or adults
Literacy
Numeracy
003 Personal skills
0031 Personal skills
Personal skills are defined by reference to the effects on the individual’s capacity (mental, 
social etc.). This detailed field covers personal skills programmes not included in 0011 ‘Basic
Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here:
```

I wanna get all lines contain 4 numbers and also all paragraph after that untill this sentence:
`Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here:`

So the out put is:

```
First_list= [0021 Literacy and numeracy,0031 Personal skills]
secend_list=[    Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for  
  adults, designed  to teach fundamental skills in reading, writing and arithmetic. The typical age range of  participants can be used to distinguish between detailed field 0011 ‘Basic programmes and qualifications’ and this detailed field. , Personal skills are defined by reference to the effects on the individual’s capacity (mental, social etc.). This detailed field covers personal skills programmes not included in 0011 ‘Basic]
```

I tried to do that but I couldn't finish it.

I tried to get the text of pdf and find keywords that I want text before or in the same line of the.

```
import re
f = open('f.pdf','rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdf_reader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
text_fefore = re.findall('Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here',text)
4_digit = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d',text)
```

So I think `text_fefore` is exactly the line that I need a paragraph before it . Also `4_digit` is  a number that I want the whole line of that.

any idea how I can finish this code?

**Note: 4 digit is in the beginning of the line.**

I should also mention that `text_fefore = re.search('Programmes and qualifications with the following main content are classified here',text)`
gives me the `span` of the start and the end of the sentence. So I know where I stop getting text but how should I find the start point?

for this one also : `4_digit = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d',text)` I should find the `span` of the end of the line. which is the answer of my the above question.

Comment: there are few more places where 4 digit numbers are there 0011 etc

Comment: @Nagakiran can I force it like it is in the beginning of the line?

Comment: @Nagakiran I edited. can you help me with this assumption? thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

you can try utilizing `nltk` library to perform sentence differentiation and picking next sentence followed by integer condition, here i added the snippet

```
import nltk
sents = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
lines = text.split('\n')
res = [[],[]]
for idx, sent in enumerate(lines):
    ints = re.findall(r'(\d+)', sent)
    if sent[:4] in ints:
        res[0].append(sent)
        res[1].append(nltk.sent_tokenize(' '.join(lines[idx+1:]))[0])
out
```

Out:

```
[['0021 Literacy and numeracy', '0031 Personal skills'],
 ['Literacy and numeracy are programmes or qualifications arranged mainly for adults, designed  to teach fundamental skills in reading, writing and arithmetic.',
  'Personal skills are defined by reference to the effects on the individual’s capacity (mental,  social etc.).']]
```

Comment: it doesn't give me the correct paragraphs!

Comment: I think space is not a good thing  for splitting lines

Comment: actually, line splitting done by '\n', which is an indicator for lines, paragraphs splitting, usually done by sentence delimiter or you can also opt for  colon splitting '.' :-| @user15649753